# List all step information BOTO

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, boto

I was wondering if there was a way I can list all information on a emr cluster step through boto. I know that the aws cli can do such a thing by `aws emr list-steps --cluster-id ID`.

This gives all information for all steps in this cluster; I want to use python and boto to do the same thing but was wondering if there is an option in boto emr where you can list all information (like the aws cli prints)...currently I have to get each information with a specific call such as:

```
    >>> conn.list_steps('j-2J699C85LW1R6').steps
    [<boto.emr.emrobject.StepSummary object at 0x107785ad0>,
     <boto.emr.emrobject.StepSummary object at 0x107798b90>,
     <boto.emr.emrobject.StepSummary object at 0x107798d90>,
     <boto.emr.emrobject.StepSummary object at 0x10778e650>,
     <boto.emr.emrobject.StepSummary object at 0x10778ea90>,]
    >>> conn.list_steps('j-2J699C85LW1R6').steps[0].id
    u's-2LLDFU54O55DJ'
    >>> conn.list_steps('j-2J699C85LW1R6').steps[0].status.state
    u'COMPLETED'
```

There are tons of little arguments like this such as `timeline.enddatetime, config.args,actiononfailure etc etc` and was wondering if there was a simple command to retrieve ALL of this information in one call to return json or something similiar.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single call, but you can get a list of steps and then iterate through them, calling describe_step on each. Here are a couple of functions from my complete example on [GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/904ccdab93220d59eb45bdc9c299288036406e5d/python/example_code/emr/emr_basics.py#L155).

```
def list_steps(cluster_id, emr_client):
    """
    Gets a list of steps for the specified cluster. In this example, all steps are
    returned, including completed and failed steps.
    :param cluster_id: The ID of the cluster.
    :param emr_client: The Boto3 EMR client object.
    :return: The list of steps for the specified cluster.
    """
    try:
        response = emr_client.list_steps(ClusterId=cluster_id)
        steps = response['Steps']
        logger.info("Got %s steps for cluster %s.", len(steps), cluster_id)
    except ClientError:
        logger.exception("Couldn't get steps for cluster %s.", cluster_id)
        raise
    else:
        return steps


def describe_step(cluster_id, step_id, emr_client):
    """
    Gets detailed information about the specified step, including the current state of
    the step.
    :param cluster_id: The ID of the cluster.
    :param step_id: The ID of the step.
    :param emr_client: The Boto3 EMR client object.
    :return: The retrieved information about the specified step.
    """
    try:
        response = emr_client.describe_step(ClusterId=cluster_id, StepId=step_id)
        step = response['Step']
        logger.info("Got data for step %s.", step_id)
    except ClientError:
        logger.exception("Couldn't get data for step %s.", step_id)
        raise
    else:
        return step
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use describe_step method to get other details.

http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/emr.html

```
describe_step(cluster_id, step_id)
Describe an Elastic MapReduce step

Parameters: 
cluster_id (str) – The cluster id of interest
step_id (str) – The step id of interest
```